# How to count each number that is generated randomly using array in C#

Tags: c#, random

How to count each number that gets generated randomly using array in C#?

Output will be as below:

2
3
5
3
5

Number 1 : 0
Number 2 : 1
Number 3 : 2
Number 4 : 0
Number 5 : 2

I did come out with random numbers but then I'm stuck to figure out how to count each number.

```
int[] randNum;
randNum = new int[5];
Random randNum2 = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < randNum.Length; i++)
{
    randNum[i] = randNum2.Next(0, 9);
    Console.Writeline(randNum[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: this is an excercise that is best solved first with pen and paper. Can you write down in your own words how you would solve it if you would have those numbers in front of you on a piece of paper?

Comment: Instead of storing the random numbers in the array, create an array big enough to encompass the range of the random numbers. Then instead of storing the random numbers in the array, use the random number as an index into the array, and increment the value at that index. Afterwards, the number at each index in the array will be the count of times that the number occurred.

Comment: @MongZhu The question is quite straight forward but I'm stuck on how to count each number randomly generated in array

Comment: with this: `randNum2.Next(0, 9);` you create numbers between `0` and `9` so when solving this on paper you would first go through your random array and count all the `0`. then you would write down `0 : 0` then you would start looking for the `1` and count it again. then for the `2`. Doesn't it sound like a loop? you wrote already 1 loop so you could write another one. That should get you started

Comment: Start by thinking about which data structure could be used to store the number of times the random number has been generated. Once you have that figured out it should be easy to get the code to increment the number each time it happens.

Comment: "I'm stuck on how to count each number" Writing down the "algorithm" in your own words of how you would solve it on paper is meant to get you unstuck. It will reveal the procedure and thus the code

Comment: @MongZhu ok got it, I need to create one more loop, am I right?

Comment: " I need to create one more loop, am I right? " in the short sense : "yes". But this excercise is meant to teach you more than just counting numbers in an array. And by asking us for a solution you are actually preventing your own brain of developing that skill. The bigger picture is how does your brain conceptualize the problem and shapes a solution (which you said yourself is straight forward) into code. Write down in normal human language how you would solve it on pen and paper and you will see that this is exactly the algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, we use `Dictionary` for such problems:

```
 // We build dictionary:
 Dictionary<int, int> counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

 // 1000 random numbers  
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
   int random = randNum2.Next(0, 9);

   if (counts.TryGetValue(random, out int count))
     counts[random] = count + 1;
   else 
     counts.Add(random, 1);    
 } 

 // Then query the dictionary, e.g. 
 // How many times 4 appeared?
 int result = counts.TryGetValue(4, out int value) ? value : 0;
```

However, if numbers are of a small range (say, `0..8`, not `-1000000..1000000000`) we can use arrays:

```
 int numbersToGenerate = 5;
 int max = 9; 

 int[] counts = new int[max];

 for (int i = 0; i < numbersToGenerate; ++i) {
   int random = randNum2.Next(0, max);

   counts[random] += 1;     
 } 

 // Output:
 for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; ++i)
   Console.WriteLine($"Number {i} : {counts[i]}");
```

Comment: Yeah I got it. I need to create one more loop and fix the first loop and var. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you want an **extra** array with the counting output of the other array.

Then i think this is a simple solution:

```
int[] arrResult = new int[9];

foreach(int number in randNum){
   if(arrResult[number] == null){
      arrResult[number] = 0;
   }
   arrResult[number] = arrResult[number] + 1;
}
```

if as i am reading in your code the numbers are from 0 to 8 so 9 numbers, this will output an Array where if the random numbers for example are 0 1 0 2 3 1 0

```
 arrResult[0] == 3
 arrResult[1] == 2
 arrResult[3] == 1
```

there probably is a more efficent way with linq and different uses but this should be a solution which would work for your problem

Comment: As i just read, if u are able to rewrite the code where the numbers are generated, you simple say in your loop `int genNumber = randNum2.Next(0, 9); randNum[i] = genNumber; arrResult[i]++` my code will work with a given array, but if you have the right to change the way your numbers are generated you can count while generating.